# How do I add tiles to a ds grid using script?

Tags: game-maker

I am new to Game Maker Studio 2; how do I add tiles to a ds grid using script?

Comment: I haven't use this, thus I don't know exactly how to use it (in particular I don't know if the ds grid has to be rectangular, if adding affects the size and whatever or not you have to set the size before adding). Regardless, what you need are the [ds grid functions](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/data%20structures/ds%20grids/index.html), experiment with them.

Answer (score 0):

I Did It After a long Research

```
for (var yy = 0; yy < height; yy++) {
    for (var xx = 0; xx < width; xx++) {
        if (grid[# xx, yy] == FLOOR) {
            // Draw the floor
                var tilemapID = layer_tilemap_get_id("Floor");
                var tileData = tilemap_get(tilemapID , xx, yy);
                tileData = tile_set_index(tileData, 1);
                tilemap_set(tilemapID, tileData, xx, yy);
        }
    }
}
```

`tile_set_index` is used to define which cell i want to place the cell the first topleft cell is 1, 2 is the one next to it and so on

`grid` is my ds grid